# Django get results from multiple rows into a list?

Tags: python, html, django, templates

For example, I have the following model:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    book = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

I want to my template to do something that results in the html below. So, for every author with the same first name, it iterate and populate the list with all the books that has the author with that first name.

```
<h3>Author First Name</h3>
<ul>
    <li>Book1</li>
    <li>Book2</li>
    <li>Book3</li>
</ul>
<h3>Author First Name2</h3>
<ul>
    <li>Book4</li>
    <li>Book9</li>
</ul
```

I'm not sure how to build a Django Queryset that would allow me to do this.

Comment: Your model design is so bad that, you can't write query such like that. First learn how to design a model with ForeignKey or OneToManyField or ManyToManyField. Good Luck :)

Comment: To give a bit more detail to @AshrafulIslam's comment - you should have another model called `Book` which is linked to `Author` via ForeignKey or other relationship.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The foreign key solution is the something I want.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to do some of this work inside your view function.

```
L1 = Author.objects.all().order_by('firstname').values('firstname', 'book')
```

will return you the list of records.

```
from itertools import group_by
from operator import itemgetter

group_by(L1, itemgetter('firstname'))
```

will give you a list of authors with books for each author.

Let us say you pass this as `list1` to your template. Then inside your template you can do:

```
{% for k, v in list1 %}
    <h3>{{ k }}</h3>
    <ul>
    {% for b in v %}
        <li>{{ b }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```